# how could cloud run instance always on 1

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a problem is in my project, set cloud run min intance :1 , max instance:1
why my cloud run metric instance count like this picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmxGF.png)

Comment: Even with Min at 1, your container can be terminated. If you want one container always running, enable that feature: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-always-on-cpu-allocation

Comment: Hi John , i set cpu allocation config like "CPU is alwyas allocated", that cant fix my problem.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Your screenshot does not indicate a problem.

Comment: I want to try slove why metircs have 0.5 instance , this value is very confuseed.